# I am making my first android app for browser and there is error in 4 line (BrowserActivity cannot be resolved to a type) which i cannot understand

Tags: java, android

BrowserActivity cannot be resolved to a type) this error is indicated in console.error is in 4 line

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(this, BrowserActivity.class);
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

Comment: Do you have BrowserActivity defined anywhere in your project?

Comment: yes i have added separate android activity name browser

Comment: verify that BrowserActivity and your MainActivity are in the same package

Comment: yes both are in the same pakage..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created BrowserActivity class? 
Create a BrowserActivity.class

Answer (score 0):

`BrowserActivity` can't be resolved to a type because it doesn't exist in your project.

Place your cursor on `BrowserActivity` it'll prompt you to create one or you can yourself create it under the required hierarchy.